# Implementing wysiwyg-rails with rails_admin not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, rails-admin

I'm building a website using Ruby on Rails with rails_admin gem for admin interface.

I'm currently trying to implement wysiwyg editor inside my admin interface using wysiwyg-rails gem.

I followed [the gem documentation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Froala-WYSIWYG-HTML-Editor). 
I created app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/ui.js for javascript and app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/custom/theming.scss for styling

However, this still has no effect on my admin interface and I don't know where to add the following code, since it causes an error when I add it to config/initializers/rails_admin.rb and has no effect when I add it to my controllers:

```
edit do
  field :content, :froala
end

# Optionally providing froala options (see https://editor.froala.com/options)
edit do
    field :content, :froala do
        config_options do
            {
                inlineMode: false,
                paragraphy: false
            }
        end
    end
end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have needs to go in your admin definitions in `app/admin`, so for whatever model you're adding the WYSIWYG editor too, it'd go in there, as you're defining how to edit the fields on that particular model.

Assuming the rest of the wysiwyg-rails gem setup is working, you should then see it being used for editing the field on the model you've added that config for.

Comment: But I don't have app/admin directory

Comment: Ah sorry, I was thinking of `ActiveAdmin` - as per the `rails-admin` docs, you can define your model specific config in a few different places: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Models. Regardless, it looks like wherever you want to define your model admin config, is where the `edit` blocks from your code above should go.